# Basement drain issue

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain, drainage, overflow

I live in a house with a drain in the basement well it wasn't installed correctly, it was raised above the cement floor. So I decided I'd fix it and I did. I Broke away the the crumbling cement removed the drain then reinstalled it using self leveling cement Sealant for concrete. Well a bunch of it seeped down the drain not completely plugging the drain but close. QUESTION: How can I get the cured sealant out short of destroying the concrete floor?

Comment: I suggest contacting the manufacturer, there might be something that might soften or dissolve it.

Comment: Maybe the drain was for a future toilet and it was raised assuming a sub-floor would be installed.   I would call a professional plumber and confess your sins.  Those guys have seen it all and can do amazing things.

Comment: Yr gonna need a drill bit the diameter of your drain pipe, mounted on a flex cable.  I rather doubt there exists a solvent for the cured stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Self leveling cement is not the toughest stuff and it will probably chip out without much trouble. I would try smacking it with a punch, not hard enough to break the pipe if plastic but if plastic I would expect the compound to break loose fairly easily.
When sealing pipes in concrete I use hydraulic cement it takes a little more work than self leveling compound.

When punching the stuff in the pipe try to pull out all the big chunks with a shop vac or by hand. I have flushed small amounts down the drain but you take a chance of it plugging up further down.

Comment: Thank you all for your input it's really appreciated. No the drain is in the basement laundry room so not a toilet fixture. Self leveling cement seal doesn't cure hard it stays rubbery..